# Finding embeded xpaths in a String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string where I have the user should be able to specify xpaths that will be evaluated at runtime. I was thinking about having a the following way to specify it.

```
String = "Hi my name is (/message/user) how can i help you with (/message/message) ";
```

How can i replace the variables with the evaluated expression?
Is there a better notation that will have less errors, since () may be used in xpaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{}` instead of `()` because `{}` are not used in XPath expressions and therefore you will not have confusions.

Comment: Can `{}` present in XPath's string?

Comment: @nhahtdh, as far as I know, no. Only `( )` and `[ ]` are used in XPath

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. <> could also be options but they could be used in html if I allow it at some point. so {} would be the best option.

Comment: @AlexR: I mean XPath also has string literal - though I'm not sure if `{}` present in string literal of XPath. If it does, then I think a caveat should be added